# os module of python regarding os.linesep

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Why has os.linesep() been used here in my code?

```
def GetInstruction():
    print(os.linesep)#<--------???
    Instruction = input("> ").lower()
    return Instruction
```

Comment: I don't know, why *was* `os.linesep` used in your code?

Comment: The line separator character(s) differ between OSs. This way the code is OS-independent.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Line ending translation happens by default, and `print` prints a line ending by default, so using `os.linesep` here doesn't make things any more OS-independent. I think this code may actually produce `\r\r\n\r\n` on Windows.

Comment: @user2357112, You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're using it, but from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep):

> The string used to separate (or, rather, terminate) lines on the current platform. This may be a single character, such as '\n' for POSIX, or multiple characters, for example, '\r\n' for Windows.

Basically represents the current line separator default for your current environment or platform.

Comment: And the part of the quote you took out: "Do not use os.linesep as a line terminator when writing files opened in text mode (the default); use a single '\n' instead, on all platforms." This includes printing to stdout with `print`. Also, `print` already prints a line ending by default anyway.